# Cannot type password. (creating a Django admin superuser)

Tags: python, django, django-admin, python-3.5

I am doing `python manage.py createsuperuser` in PowerShell and CMD, and I can type when it prompts me for the Username and Email, but when it gets to Password it just won't let me type. It is not freezing though, because when I press enter it re-prompts me for the password...

Using Django 1.10 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While it does not show you what you are typing, it is still taking the input. So just type in the password both times, press enter and it will work even though it does not show up.